# is using a debugging browser detectable?

Tags: python, selenium

I just wanted to know is it detectable for webpages that we use a debugging mode browser like the below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# already opened a browser in debugging mode at port 8989

opt = Options()
opt.add_experimental_option('debuggerAddress', 'localhost:8989')
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="my driver path", chrome_options=opt)
driver.get('http://google.com')
```

Comment: It's not trivial but it is detectable.

Comment: @KlausD. , I actually want to know if this method is better than using normal selenium,  for opening webpages that are sensitive to automated software & have bot detection system, is it?

Comment: Maybe this thread could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66989755/getting-403-when-using-selenium-to-automate-checkout-process/67070031#67070031

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Selenium is fairly easily detected, especially by all major anti-bot providers (Cloudflare, Akamai, etc).

**Why?**

1. Selenium, and most other major webdrivers set a browser variable (that websites can access) called `navigator.webdriver` to `true`. You can check this yourself by heading to your Google Chrome console and running `console.log(navigator.webdriver)`. If you're on a normal browser, it will be false.
2. The User-Agent, typically all devices have what is called a "user agent", this refers to the device accessing the website. Selenium's User-Agent looks something like this: `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36`. Did you catch that? `HeadlessChrome` is included, this is another route of detection.

These are just two of the multiple ways a Selenium browser can be detected, I would highly recommend reading up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56529616/6126726) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904) as well.

And lastly, if you want an easy, drop-in solution to bypass detection that implements almost all of these concepts we've talked about, I'd suggest using [undetected-chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver). This is an open source project that tries it's best to keep your Selenium chromedriver looking human.